# Is it possible to command a common router without using the web interface?

Tags: networking, router, automation

### Some background

The internet arrangement in my student home is really weird. There is one ethernet outlet and several wifi hotspots. Either way requires a login through a web site to get internet access. This is annoying as each device needs to login seperately and with a PS3 for example, it is impossible to get connected at all since the web login procedure doesn't work.

Therefore I have installed a `D-Link DIR-635` router which is connected to the ethernet outlet. It has DHCP enabled so it uses NAT, but whatever it is connected to also uses NAT and I've read this should not work. A fellow student tried it with an Apple Airport but that keeps giving errors related to NAT after NAT. Anyway my setup does work so bonus points if you can clarify this.

I need to login to the web site I mentioned earlier with **any** device, after which **all devices** in my LAN have connectivity. This is great. Except...

### In short

From time to time, I lose internet connectivity and my `D-Link DIR-635` router needs to do a DHCP renew. I can do this via the web interface but my life would be easier if I could just run a `cmd` file which tells my router to do this without all the hassle. This would setup a connection to my router and execute the proper command. I have tried googling but couldn't find much helpful stuff.

Comment: For a D-Link with default firmware, no. It does not have SSH capability. DD-wrt (if able to be installed on that router) will let you log in via SSH, and therefore run commands remotely. If you don't want to mess with your firmware, you can look at Autoit for interfacing with a webpage (auto-login and navigation via web controls).

Comment: @MaQleod DD-wrt looks interesting, unfortunately my router is not supported. Autoit seems nice but there isn't much gain as it's not the number of clicks involved or something but merely the loading times of the web interface that fluctuate. Is SSH the only protocol for the purpose? What about telnet?

Answer (score 2):

NAT is going to make everything behind it look like one system.  It's not optimal, but seems to be the best thing you can do if your campus is requiring each unique device to log in.

First, if video game systems are not prohibited under your campus policy, talk to someone in your school's IT department and see if they can exempt your PS3's MAC from whatever security they have setup.  Remind them that you are paying to go there, if their terms and conditions don't prohibit that.

It's possible to write a script that automates the sign on to your school's gateway page.  It's possible to run scripts from third-party firmware such as DD-WRT or OpenWRT, but generally not any typical stock router firmware.  So if you really want to do this from your router, switch to a router that lets you flash it to one of those systems.  WRT54G's are cheap on E-bay.  Alternatively you could set up a desktop or laptop with Internet Connection Sharing or set up a Linux desktop or laptop as router.

Furthermore, writing such a script is not trivial, but not very difficult if you are familiar with a language like Perl and have tools to sniff the HTML coming back and forth between you and whatever system is asking you to sign in.  There are Firefox addons and programs that will capture an HTML exchange between you and a remote host.  Basically, you'll need to create a script that outputs the same things as your browser would, likely incorporating things like cookies or hidden form fields in the initial page the system sends you asking you to sign in.

If your school requires you to solve a captcha to sign in though, forget it.

You could try looking at the HTML source and see if it's a well known system that's performing the gateway function, there may just be a tool out there that does it.  If not, you'll have to make your own.

Comment: Okay forgive me if this was not clear but when I meant student home I meant a privately rented house with a couple of rooms and a shared kitchen and showers. Your explanation is handy but not so relevant to my question. The problem here is to renew the WAN IP on my router in the most convenient way possible. The little side question was why NAT after NAT works in my case and not in my friend's case.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Actually, just use telnet, is telnet enabled by default on your router? If not, i'm sure you can turn it on. If you want, i can login to your router via telnet to figure out the command that is necessary to run, then i can hook you up with the automation software that will login using telnet and run that command for you whenever you want, either on a schedule or whenever you double click an icon on your desktop. let me know.

Comment: @user51047 what, how do you know you can log in to his router via telnet.. you're writing liek english is not your first language. You don't know whether he has telnet support.. you should state what percentage of routers you think have it, or why you think his router has telnet support. You don't know his IP and if he has telnet I doubt he has it on his public IP, so don't claim you can log into his router(besides the fact that you don't know his password)..